# No audio devices under linux

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I'm using Fedora 32, but the issue started from version 31: I simply do not see any sound device under Settings -> Sound.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDOcY.png)

These are the outputs from commands I have seen requested on the internet when dealing with sound issues:

`ls -l /dev/snd`

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       60 jun  9 20:29 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 11 jun  9 20:29 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 jun  9 20:29 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 jun  9 20:29 hwC0D2
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 jun  9 20:46 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 jun  9 20:46 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 jun  9 20:46 pcmC0D10p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 jun  9 20:46 pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 jun  9 20:46 pcmC0D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 jun  9 20:46 pcmC0D8p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 jun  9 20:46 pcmC0D9p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 jun  9 20:29 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 jun  9 20:29 timer
```

`groups`

`eric wheel audio`

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3271 Analog [ALC3271 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav`

```
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

aplay: main:830: audio open error: Connection refused
```

`ls .config/pulse`

```
0e07bbc7e383453fa4827474edd6cfb7-card-database.tdb  0e07bbc7e383453fa4827474edd6cfb7-device-volumes.tdb
0e07bbc7e383453fa4827474edd6cfb7-default-sink       0e07bbc7e383453fa4827474edd6cfb7-stream-volumes.tdb
0e07bbc7e383453fa4827474edd6cfb7-default-source
```

`pulseaudio -v`

```
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 13.99.1-rebootstrapped
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 0e07bbc7e383453fa4827474edd6cfb7.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/eric/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib64/pulse-13.99/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

In case it helps, I am using a Dell XPS-13 9370

Comment: Please add the output of the `dmesg` command to your question.

Comment: Just solved it comparing the `/etc/pulse/` folder with that of a Fedora Live Image.

Comment: Then please add your solution as an answer and accept it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: somehow, the configuration file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` got some lines commented. Uncommenting them solved the issue after a reboot.
Below, the lines I had to uncomment:

```
### Load several protocols
.ifexists module-esound-protocol-unix.so
load-module module-esound-protocol-unix
.endif
load-module module-native-protocol-unix
```